# A filter for two conditions at the same time on album tracks

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
dataset_ex <- data.frame(album = c("Brim","Brim","Brum","Brum"),
                         track = c("Tad","Toe","Toe","Ram"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  album track
1  Brim   Tad
2  Brim   Toe
3  Brum   Toe
4  Brum   Ram
```

And one song track is redundant (since it appeared in two albums). In this case, the song `Toe`. And I want to eliminate one observation with that song, so I tried:

```
dataset_ex %>% filter(track != "Toe" && album != "Brum")
```

But it returns all the observations. My expected result is:

```
  album track
1  Brim   Tad
2  Brim   Toe
3  Brum   Ram
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I appreciate the two answers below, however I would like to know why a dual condition won't work here. Please, if you have a solution in that way it will help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When comparing vectors you should use single `&` or `|` and I think the condition that you are looking for is `|` here -

```
library(dplyr)

dataset_ex %>% filter(track != "Toe" | album != "Brum")

#  album track
#1  Brim   Tad
#2  Brim   Toe
#3  Brum   Ram
```

Keep the rows where `track` is not `'Toe'` or `album` is not `'Brum'`.

---

Another way -

This gives the row that you want to remove

```
dataset_ex %>% filter(track == "Toe" & album == "Brum")

#  album track
#1  Brum   Toe
```

Now negate the above condition to get the rows that you want to keep -

```
dataset_ex %>% filter(!(track == "Toe" & album == "Brum"))

#  album track
#1  Brim   Tad
#2  Brim   Toe
#3  Brum   Ram
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct()` on `track`, keeping all other columns in the dataframe.

```
dataset_ex <- distinct(dataset_ex, track, .keep_all = TRUE)
dataset_ex

#   album track
# 1  Brim   Tad
# 2  Brim   Toe
# 3  Brum   Ram
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you

```
library(dplyr)
dataset_ex %>% distinct(track, .keep_all= TRUE)
```